# Sorting a list of strings by custom key

Tags: python, string, sorting

I recently had a live coding interview, and was asked to solve a relatively simple problem:

Given a list of two-character strings in an arbitrary order, write a function that returns a list of the same strings, sorted first by strings containing both alpha and numeric characters in ascending order, followed by numerical-only strings in ascending order.

I was able to solve this fairly quickly with the below:

```
polelist = ['13', '2', '20', '3', '30', '1a', '1b', '1', '3c', '2a', 'a1', '2b', '10', 'aa']

def sortpoles(poles):
    alphapoles = []
    numpoles = []

    for item in poles:
        if item.isnumeric():
            numpoles.append(item)
        else:
            alphapoles.append(item)

    numpoles = [int(x) for x in numpoles]
    numpoles.sort()
    numpoles = [str(x) for x in numpoles]

    alphapoles.sort()

    alphapoles.extend(numpoles)

    return alphapoles
```

This returns: `['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3c', 'a1', 'aa', '1', '2', '3', '10', '13', '20', '30']` which is the correct answer.

With the remaining time, they asked me if I could find a more efficient way to do this. I know that both `sort()` and `sorted()` can accept a "key" argument with a function for custom sort criteria, but I wasn't able to figure out the logic to accomplish this. I've been trying to solve this for my own edification for the last couple hours but I'm stumped. Is this even the right approach for improving the efficiency of my solution? Is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Since your code doesn't really have a problem and you're not asking about a specific problem (other than how to apply `sort`'s `key`) here, this is more of a code review question than an SO question. I'd recommend asking the same question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of the difference. I think I'll do that.

Comment: When someone asks "better" in an interview, it may be a good idea to ask clarification what that means, .e.g, memory, speed, code lines, readability, maintainability, etc. This also shows engagement and not jumping straight into a task with unclear specifications. For example, writing an one-liner which requires a comment to be understood may not be preferable over a 3-line self-documented method. Or it could be they wanted to see you defending your approach if it is indeed optimal. Not to imply there weren't improvements to be made to your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clean solution:

```
polelist = ['13', '2', '20', '3', '30', '1a', '1b', '1', '3c', '2a', 'a1', '2b', '10', 'aa']

result = sorted(polelist, key=lambda x: (x.isnumeric(), int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x))
print(result)
```

It's similar to what I just noticed @GIOVANNIQUINONESVALDEZ posted, but since your description didn't mention negative numbers being excluded, I wouldn't want to rely on length.

Output:

```
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3c', 'a1', 'aa', '1', '2', '3', '10', '13', '20', '30']
```

This is more efficient not because of its brevity (although it's also shorter and , in my opinion, more readable), but because it avoids needlessly copying the lists and later recombining them.

Also, `sorted` ensures each key is only computed once, when needed, so there's no losses there.

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest solution, but does the job.

```
>>> polelist.sort(key = lambda x : (x.isnumeric(), len(x)))
['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3c', 'a1', 'aa', '1', '2', '3', '10', '13', '20', '30']
```

The logic is to sort first by bool (is numeric or not), and the by the length of the string as larger numbers --> larger length and numbers of the same length are intrinsically sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already NlogN and there is technically no more efficient way, but coding can be shorten

```
print(list(sorted(polelist,key=lambda x:(x.isnumeric(),int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x))))
```

Comment: `list()` is unnecessary as `sorted` already returns a list.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if by "make it more efficient", the interviewer just wanted to see if I could refactor into something shorter. Thanks!